# How to split into a 2-dimensional array python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to split the lines in a file into 2 separate (2-dimensional) array.

E.g. Username : password array (`users[user][pass]`)

This is the code I have come up with so far :

```
with open('userlist.txt', 'r') as userlist:
    for line in userlist:
        user, pwd = line.strip().split(':')
        users = [
             [user, pwd]
                ]
```

Please help. This code currently only lists all of the usernames and all of the passwords. But I want to be able to call the username with the password pair by the same index (e.g. `print(users[1][1])`)

Comment: Could you send an example string from userlist.txt?

Comment: You can use `user = line.strip().split(':')[0]` and `pwd = line.strip().split(':')[1]` **IF** your first column in the file is always user and the second is password

Comment: Pls provide sample input and output. `array (users[user][pass])` is rather unclear.

Comment: Do you want `[[user1, user2], [pwd1, pwd2]]` or `[[user1, pwd1], [user2, pwd2]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you described in your question, you want to add a new list [user, password] to an existing list of all users every time you loop over userlist.

You can do it this way:

```
    users = []
    with open('userlist.txt', 'r') as userlist:
        for line in userlist:
            user, pwd = line.strip().split(':')
            users.append([user, pwd])
```

But for this situation there's a better solution using dictionaries:

```
    users = {}
    with open('userlist.txt', 'r') as userlist:
        for line in userlist:
            user, pwd = line.strip().split(':')
            users[user] = pwd
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should suffice. Note that you have to initialize the outer data structure *before* the loop and fill it in the loop:

```
with open('userlist.txt', 'r') as userlist:
  users = []
  for line in userlist:
    users.append(line.strip().split(':'))
```

which can be shortened to:

```
with open('userlist.txt', 'r') as userlist:
  users = [line.strip().split(':') for line in userlist]
```

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you do it this way

```
file=open('userlist.txt', 'r')
line=file.readlines()
users=[l.strip.split(':') for l in line]
```

what this does is that it takes a line, "uname":"pass", splits it with ":" which gives you `["uname","pass"]` and it saves it in each index of the users array

you can now access username via `[users[i][0]]` and passwords via `users[i][1]`